# Detect image path in HTML image reference and create a link

Tags: jquery, html

How do i detect the path of a HTML image reference and add a specific hyperlink reference.

For example:

```
<div class="description">
    <img src="https://www.example.com/image/hello.jpg">
</div>
```

After a script detects the image url it should build a code like this:

```
<div class="description">
    <a class="fancybox" href="https://www.example.com/image/hello.jpg">
      <img src="https://www.example.com/image/hello.jpg">
    </a>
</div>
```

I think i need a script, but i have no experience in javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you add a class to each img unless you plan on doing this for every img tag.

```
$("img").wrap(function(){
    return $("<a>").attr("href", $(this).attr("src")).addClass("fancybox");
});
```

Update: For all images inside the description class, you can use

```
$(".description img").wrap(function(){
    return $("<a>").attr("href", $(this).attr("src")).addClass("fancybox");
});
```

This finds all img inside the description class.

I would still advice you to use a class for each img too. This will help you in case in future you decide to have an image such as a logo within the description which does not need this wrap. If you do that you need to update the selector to `$(".description img.myclass")`.

Comment: thanks very much sir! It works! No, I dont want to use this on every img tag. How do i restrict this script only inside the "description"-class?